# php array declaration causes unintended functionality

Tags: php, arrays

```
$tally['zero']['status']='hello';
echo $tally['zero']['status'];
//prints hello, this is expected
```

In this example, why is only the first letter being printed?

```
$tally = array( "zero" => '0');     
$tally['zero']['status']='hello';
echo $tally['zero']['status'];   
// prints h, I was expecting hello
```

In this example, why is an error being thrown?

```
$tally['zero'] = 0;
$tally['zero']['status']='hello';
echo $tally['zero']['status'];
//prints Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In this example, why is only the first letter being printed?
>
> ```
> $tally = array( "zero" => '0');
> $tally['zero']['status'] = 'hello';
> echo $tally['zero']['status']; // h
> ```

In PHP, strings can be indexed like arrays, and can also be modified in place. So `'status'` becomes `0` when indexing the string, and the first character of `hello` is assigned to the first letter of `$tally['zero']`. For example, this:

```
$tally = array( "zero" => '01');
$tally['zero']['status'] = 'hello';
echo $tally['zero'];
```

Would print "h1".

---

> In this example, why is an error being thrown?
>
> ```
> $tally['zero'] = 0;
> $tally['zero']['status'] = 'hello';
> echo $tally['zero']['status'];
> ```

Like the error says, `0` is not an array. You can't index it, hence the warning.

Comment: Non-integer indexes for strings was removed as of PHP 5.4: http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.incompatible.php

Comment: PHP 5.4 would throw an `E_WARNING` in the situation you described, guiding the dev closer to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

be careful about using " and '. While using " content can be interpreted as a varaible value.

```
0 != '0'   number/string
```

I think that all mystery is hidden here.

Comment: No. In PHP, 0 == '0'. For exact type checks, one must use !== or ===. That is not the origin of the question.

Comment: Means not equal. It's not php code. Will you explain me its not possible divide number by string too? Compare first rows of example 2 a 3.